# JS pushing objects into an array within an object

Tags: javascript

I'm getting data from a webservice and I would like to push it into an array within an object like this

```
   var createTimesheetFromWebserviceData = function (timesheetData) {

            for (var key in timesheetData.urenstaatRegels) {
                var timesheet = {
                    Id: timesheetData.urenstaatId,
                    Owner: timesheetData.urenGebruiker,
                    Rows: [
                        {
                            Days: {
                                Monday: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].aant_ma,
                                Tuesday: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].aant_di,
                                Wednesday: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].aant_wo,
                                Thursday: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].aant_do,
                                Friday: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].aant_vr,
                                Saturday: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].aant_za,
                                Sunday: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].aant_zo
                            },
                            Activity: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].activiteit,
                            Hourtype: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].type_soort_uur,
                            Traction: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].produktiemiddel2,
                            Remark: timesheetData.urenstaatRegels[key].redenAfkeuring
                        }
                    ],
                    Status: timesheetData.status,
                    SubmittedDateTime: timesheetData.opvoerDatum
                }

                    timesheet.Rows.push(timesheet.Rows); // I want to try something like this, but this just overrides the previous timesheet.

            }
            return timesheet;
        }
```

So in the `for` loop I want to create multiple rows within the object timesheet. I want to push more rows into the existing timesheet.

edit: I want the timesheet object to be the same, I just want to push extra Row objects onto the timesheet object.

this data comes from a webservice and is totally different in setup, thats why i want to use this timesheet object to communicate with angular. It is not possible to just use the object as I get it from the webservice.

I tried to push the rows onto the timesheet, but it just overrides them. What is the correct way to handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

You overiding you timesheet variable inside loop.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I want to just add extra rows to the Rows array within the loop. The rest of the timesheet can stay the same.

Comment: I dont get whats your goal, this code doesent have any sense, your doing twice same thing.

Comment: The goal of this code is to build up a timesheet so i can use it in my angular frontend that already excists. So i get the data from a webservice and create timesheet objects from that data. Every timesheet should have 1 or more Rows arrays. So i want (in a for loop) add the Rows arrays into the timesheet object.

Comment: Please add an example of timesheetData which comes from api